# Fake a long running SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to fake a long running SQL statement so I can experiment with [sys.dm_exec_requests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx)

"Fake" isn't the best way to describe it, but does anyone have a good tip on perhaps selecting autogenerated records? Perhaps using a CTE?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Here's a long-running SQL statement:

```
WAITFOR DELAY '0:05';
```

It will take around five minutes to execute.

Answer (score 7):

In one query window, execute the following:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT * from TableY with (XLOCK)
```

Then, in another window, execute any(*) query that attempts to access `TableY`. And it will run for as long as you like until you close the first window or execute a `ROLLBACK` or `COMMIT` in it.

(*) assuming you don't add a `NOLOCK` hint to the reference to `TableY`.

Comment: Thanks, I like this one for seeing the table locks.

Comment: [This isn't guaranteed to work](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/11/01/read-committed-shared-locks-and-rollbacks.aspx)

Comment: Hey @MartinSmith , the link is dead :(

Answer (score 1):

Just as I was writing "CTE"... it made me think. A quick search later and a variation on 
http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/t-sql-using-common-table-expressions-cte-to-generate-sequences/

```
--define start and end limits
Declare @start bigint, @end bigint
Select @start=1, @end=99999

;With NumberSequence( Number ) as
(
    Select @start as Number
        union all
    Select Number + 1
        from NumberSequence
        where Number < @end
)

--select result
Select * From NumberSequence Option (MaxRecursion 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like Alex KeySmith's CTE answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14138219/318411 because you can apply it to your own queries; this means you can return valid data in a long running form.

So for example if you have a test table with a couple of rows in but you want to quickly know how your application code performs with large result sets, you can do the following:

```
    declare @i int, @c int
    select @i = 1, @c = 10;
    with X as (
        select @i as N union all select N + 1 from x where N < @c
    )
    select 
        T.*
    from
        X,
    (   
        select 
            *
        from
            MySmallTestTable
    ) AS T
    option (MaxRecursion 0)
```

This will repeat the test data `@c` times.

I have also used it to test query cancellation code.